# Stop threading in Python

Tags: python, error-handling, python-multithreading, blender

I have a simple problem. If I run my code all in one go (3 sections), then it doesn't work.
But, if I split those 3 sections into 3 functions, and run them each separately (run the first while commenting out the other 2, comment out the 1st and run only the 2nd, then run only the 3rd), it works.
How can I simulate this sequence of running individual functions in Python?
I've tried using time.sleep(30), but it still doesn't work.
My understanding is that I'm trying to prevent threading (it doesn't work because the parts which run at the same time make my code fail).

Comment: Try post the error message or the full code.

Comment: please type a code snippet to provide more clear details